# Can the numbers be displayed even when the bar chart is organized tidily?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QDAV.jpg)

I cannot expand more, because it will influence in other visuals.

This is the standard bar chart in Power BI. Do you recommend other visuals? Or is there something in the settings I should change?

I tried to expand a bit, but sometimes the numbers do not appear.